# Rewriting Javascript Objects to Dart Maps/Lists

Tags: dart

I'm trying to convert the following javascript object to a Dart map:

```javascript
var users = { 
    1 : {
      first_name: 'James',
      last_name: 'Smith',
      email: 'jsmith@example.com',
    },
    2 : {
      first_name: 'Robin',
      last_name: 'Doe',
      email: 'rdoe@example.com',
    }
```

I've tried:

```dart
var users = { 
    "1" : {
      first_name: 'James',
      last_name: 'Smith',
      email: 'jsmith@example.com',
    },
    "2" : {
      first_name: 'Robin',
      last_name: 'Doe',
      email: 'rdoe@example.com',
    }
```

but I'm unable to use it as a map with the numbers in quotes or without(throws errors).

```dart
var keys = users.getKeys(); //NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'getKeys'
assert(keys.length == 2);
assert(new Set.from(keys).contains('2'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use (single or double) quotes for attribute names:

```dart
var users = {
   "1" : {
     "first_name": "James",
     "last_name": "Smith",
     "email": "jsmith@example.com",
   },
   "2" : {
     "first_name": "Robin",
     "last_name": "Doe",
     "email": "rdoe@example.com"
   }
 };
```

Also, `getKeys` method does not exists, use `keys` instead:

```dart
 var keys = users.keys;
 assert(keys.length == 2);
 assert(keys.contains("2"));
 assert(users["1"]["first_name"] == "James");
```